# Rationalize the denominator of the surd, giving your answer in the simplest form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rationalize the denominator of the surd, giving your answer in the simplest form.

$\frac {3}{\sqrt2+5} $

Please help me...

It must be like this right?

$\frac {3}{\sqrt2+5} * \frac{\sqrt2-5}{\sqrt2-5}$

Comment: yes it is!! $${{}}$$

Comment: Yes; now just multiply out the denominator, using the distributive property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've got a great start. Now, simply multiply the numerators and the denominators,

$$\frac {3}{\sqrt2+5} * \frac{\sqrt2-5}{\sqrt2-5} = \dfrac{3(\sqrt 2 -5)}{(\sqrt 2 + 5)(\sqrt 2 - 5)}$$ - and in the denominator, use the fact that $$(a +b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$$

Answer (score 2):

I think it is right. after this operation denominator will be rational.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. in general we do not leave the denominator irrational. So we multiply and divide the fraction by the conjugate of denominator.

In this case the conjugate of $\sqrt{2}+5$ is $\sqrt{2}-5$.
$$\frac{3(\sqrt{2}-5)}{(\sqrt{2}+5)(\sqrt{2}-5)}$$
$$\frac{3\sqrt 2 - 15}{2-25} = \frac{3\sqrt 2 - 15}{-23}$$
$$\frac{15 - 3\sqrt{2}}{23}$$

Comment: You're incorrect: $(\sqrt 2 + 5)(\sqrt 2 - 5) \neq 4 - 5$. $$(\sqrt 2 + 5)(\sqrt 2 - 5) = (\sqrt 2)^2 - (5)^2 = 2 - 25 = -23$$